# aes/cbc/pkcs5padding encrypt and decrypt for flutter

Tags: flutter, encryption, error-handling, aes

```
static String encKey = 'oasterw4567ncdsagfhswtoslfiessgv';
  static final key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8(encKey);
  static final iv = encrypt.IV.fromLength(16);

  static final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(
      encrypt.AES(key, mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc, padding: 'PKCS7'));

  static encryptAES(text) {
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(text, iv: iv);
    print("Encrypted " + encrypted.base64);
    decryptAES(encrypted.base64);
    return encrypted.base64;
  }

  static decryptAES(encText) {
    String original =
        encrypter.decrypt(encrypt.Encrypted.from64(encText), iv: iv);
    print("Decrypt  " + original);
  }
```

> this is simple AES algo but now client required aes/cbc/pkcs5padding so how can i convert this ?

Comment: In most cases, PKCS7 = PKCS5, so you can use your algorithm :-)